# How to get vscode to write to a (python) file upon creation?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is an offshoot of the question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66050221/15339613).

I want to create a new (python) file, and everytime I do so, I want vscode to write to the file the `def main if name main` idiom:

```
def main():
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
  pass
```

Is there a json file I can write to?
More broadly, can I do this for any file I create like having

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

}
```

for c++ be written for me when I create a new c++ file?

Comment: An answer on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614398/vscode-triggering-a-snippet-upon-file-creation) suggests the extension called [Auto Snippet](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.auto-snippet).

Comment: you can use extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) or use VSC Snippets that gets inserted in file creation

Answer (score 1):

You can read [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) about snippets.

1. Open File-> Preference -> Configure user snippets
2. Type python and choose the first one.

[image]

3. Add the following codes to your `python.json`:

```json
"Print to console": {
    "prefix": "main",
    "body": [
        "def main():",
        "    pass",
        "if __name__ == \"__main__\":",
        "    pass"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
}
```

Then when you type `main` you can get the intellisense.

[image].

Another way is to use [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=huynh-quang-phuc.create-file-from-template), you can create a template file for example:

**main.py**

```
def main():
    pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Then use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type **"Files: New Template From File"**.

When you want to use this template, you can use **"File: New File From Template"** and choose this **main.py**